# how to connect a flask chat application with dialogflow version 2 API

Tags: python-3.x, flask, dialogflow-es

I want to connect my chat application with dialogflow version 2 which is already running on version 2 using client access token. But now i want to connect it with the new authorization system that the version 2 provides which includes google cloud account and google SDK system.

i have already done with the documentation that is provided by dialogflow https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup
now please help me by sharing some code snippet that can connect my application  with dialogflow V2 which is running on flask socket-io framework.

Comment: Please share your updated setup.

Comment: @Gaurav Jeswani I have followed each and every step of dialogflow docs
link: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup
now i need help to know that how can i connect it programmatically.
Thanks!